# c# copy/exists/delete/list, remote, power shell

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access

i'm new in power shell
i need to do few operations using c# on remote machine:

- copy file/dir from local to remote
- get file/dir list from remote
- check file exists from remote
- delete file/dir from remote

i have only ip address of remote machine and port (not default 5985) to power shell connection; machine doesn't have public name and doestn't have 139,445 ports shared

i think a good idea to use File.Exists, File.Copy, ... so i tried to mount

```
New-PsDrive -Root 80.240.xxx.xxx:yyyy -credential User -Name X -PSProvider filesystem
```

error:
    Корень диска "80.240.xxx.xxx:yyyy" не существует или не является папкой. (Root of disk "80.240.xxx.xxx:yyyy" doesnt exists or not a folder)

can somebody help me with an example?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from `Get-Help New-PSDrive`:

> -Root <String>
>      Specifies the data store location to which a Windows PowerShell drive is mapped.
>   
>      For example, specify a network share (such as \\Server01\Public), a local directory (such as C:\Program Files), or a registry key (such as HKLM:\Software\Microsoft).

The argument of the parameter `-Root` must have the form `\\hostname\share` or `\\ip_address\share`. No port specification with either hostname or IP address is allowed. The cmdlet requires access to port 445 on the remote host.

You probably need to set up a VPN between the two hosts, to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly it's difficult to use vpn in my case; are there any other solutions expect vpn? It's better if they ll be based on simple File.*.